# R flextable proc_freq remove label column

Tags: r, flextable, officer

Is there a way to remove the label column from the `proc_freq()` flextable after it has been created?

When a flextable is created from scratch, i.e. from a dataframe, one can specify with `col_keys` the columns to display. However, proc_freq() generates the table itself.

How do I remove the "label" column in the following table?

```
library(flextable)
proc_freq(mtcars, "cyl", "gear")
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

These are 2 ways to do it :

```
library(flextable)
library(magrittr)
proc_freq(mtcars, "cyl", "gear") %>% 
  set_header_labels(label = "")

proc_freq(mtcars, "cyl", "gear") %>% 
  compose(i = 2, j = 2, value = as_paragraph(""), part = "header")
```

Comment: Thanks David! This only removes the label text but I was referring to the entire label column, i.e. remove completely column 2. I want to save space. Should this be then a combination of emptying the cells and merging with column 1?

Comment: you can't delete a column from a flextable. yep, you could empty/merge